# complement vs adjunct/modifier

Tags: modifiers, complements, adjuncts

In the following noun phrase, is the prepositional phrase `from Lloyds` complement or adjunct/modifier?

> *even all the preposterous salary from Lloyds that Bill gets*

The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language (by Huddleston and Pullum) marks the PP as complement in the following tree diagram, but I'm not sure.

[image]

[Edit]
The reason I'm not sure about it being complement is twofold. Semantically, the noun `salary` doesn't seem to license the PP. Syntactically, the PP is a sister to N' (= Head: Nom) and a daughter to N', which means that the PP is an adjunct (a modifier in CGEL) in X-bar theory.

Comment: Why "not sure?"

Comment: @Kris See my edit.

Comment: Trying to analyse from a basic understanding about language (rather than through the filter of some particular approach), I think that there's a grey area, a sliding scale in ' "adjunctness" ' vs 'a "**necessary**" part of the immediate string'. Of course, this hinges on what is deemed 'necessary', and – when one gets to particular types of grammar – how 'complement' etc are chosen to be defined....

Comment: Obviously, 'preposterous' is a separate evaluatory adjective, which could be omitted (though even here, deletion would leave a string not sounding as natural). It can be argued that 'salary from Lloyds'  is cohesive enough to mean that deletion of the PP (while grammatically no problem) alters a unit (though not as much as deleting say 'peanut' in 'peanut butter'). Is 'salary from Lloyds'  being seen as more cohesive than 'a man from Eccles' or less cohesive than 'a bolt from the blue'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If it really is a complement, how come _salary_ is combined first with _preposterous_ (an adjunct) and then with _from Lloyds_? What I'm saying is that the tree structure is treating _from Lloyds_ as an adjunct.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not delving into various analytical schemes/schemata. Your title question as clarified in the first sentence following does not address diagramming. And I don't intend to. //  Aren't the authors of CGEL the ones to ask about the decisions they took?

Comment: I see it this way, depending on the broader context/ author's intention, it **acts** either as a complement or an adjunct. Grammar allows either interpretation. After all, something that's basically a noun can "act" as a noun, an adjunct, an adjective, even as a verb .... It depends, right? In the given context, the author apparently considers "from Lloyds" as a natural adjunct to "salary" (that exists pre-facto) and adds his commentary in the form of the adjective "preposterous" that is emphasized in the sentence -- it's the point of the whole sentence.

Comment: @JK2 "What I'm saying is that the tree structure is treating from Lloyds as an adjunct." Is it really? I don't see your point. For me the tree structure is treating "from Lloyds" as the complement of the noun "salary" with its adjunct "preposterous". You seem to imply that nouns with adjuncts must not have complements. Is that a recognized grammar rule? If so, is it because a complement always has a stronger binding to the noun than an adjunct? Would you be happier if the noun "salary" with the complement "from Lloyds" had the adjunct "preposterous"?

Comment: @BenA. If you know anything about the basics of tree diagram, you will see my point.

Comment: @JK2 As to my understanding of tree diagrams, the leaves "preposterous" and "salary" are unified in their common node to an entity (noun with adjunct) which is still a noun. This entity is unified to a new entity with the complement "from Lloyds" (another leaf) in their common node. That's what I have written in my "For me the tree structure..."  sentence. Please tell me if it's completely wrong as, being a senior software developer, I should definitely know the basics of tree diagrams.